# PHP Should Variables be Declared Outside Loops?

Tags: php

Since PHP is so dynamic, does it matter if variables are declared inside a loop?

```
while (true){
    $i = 0;
}
```

**Or**

```
$i;
while (true){
    $i = 0;
}
```

Comment: It's good practice to set a default value before the loop, then only change the value if you need to while inside the loop. `Does it matter` - no. If you error reporting is on a low setting, you won't notice a difference, but if it's turned up high you may encounter undefined variable errors if using a variable which hasn't been declared because conditions inside the loop haven't been met.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$i;` is not a variable declaration in php, since you can only declare a variable if you initialize it with a value.

It will do literally nothing.

And - no, you should not do that.